# How can I run an ASP.NET website globally [or atleast in my LAN]

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking

I made a site using VS10 Ultimate [ASP.NET] and when I build & run it runs the severer *locally*, while I want to test it for security issues via Linux.

How can I run it globally ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "run it globally"? Do you mean "how do I run it on a dedicated server?" ? or do you mean "how do I use remote *debugging* with it on a different server?" ? or...? what?

Comment: Are you running it from within visual studio? Guess what - developer web servers (integrated, IIS express) are configured to not accept non-local connections. IIS express can be reconfigured (use google), the integrated web server can not. This is a dev environment, install a server environment.

Comment: I mean I want to run in like WAMP does - like a regular website. I'm not too good with this microsoft-bs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up the site in IIS Server installed in your Windows machine to run it locally

See the links to learn more:

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Set-Up-IIS-ASP.NET.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323972

Answer (score 5):

Your development machine probably has IIS installed. Copy the code or the compiled code to the web root of this installation. If you want to put it on another computer, then that will need to have IIS, relevant version of .Net installed.

It would also help if you can setup your local DNS to resolve the name for your computer within the LAN setup so that you can reache the machine using a name rather than the IP.

This will allow you to test the security issues that are client side. For Server side security issues, you will need to create a server in your LAN that is configured similar to the actual server where you would be hosting your site.

Answer (score 1):

You need an [ASP.NET hosting service](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enAU440AU440&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asp.net%20hosting#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enAU440AU440&source=hp&q=asp.net%20hosting&pbx=1&oq=asp.net%20hosting&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3209l3392l1l3580l2l2l0l0l0l1l244l244l2-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=94458c7d4a23e13a&biw=1366&bih=653).